Why does this Rust Hyper app hang at 6 stream requests?
I have a Rust app which is running a Hyper server and uses zipit to handle on-the-fly zip archive creation.
Everything works perfectly, but the only problem is that it seems to only handle 6 streams at once. Any other requests hang until another stream is done.
use hyper::service::{make_service_fn, service_fn};
use hyper::{header, Body, Request, Response, Server, StatusCode};
use tokio::io::{duplex, AsyncWriteExt};
use tokio_util::io::ReaderStream;
use zipit::{Archive, FileDateTime};
use futures::stream::TryStreamExt;

async fn zip_archive(_req: Request<Body>) -> Result<Response<Body>, hyper::http::Error> {
    println!("Entering function");
    let file_urls = vec![
      // vec of &str
    ];

    let (w, r) = duplex(16 * 1024);
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        let mut archive = Archive::new(w);

        for (idx, url) in file_urls.iter().enumerate() {
            let bytes = reqwest::get(url.to_string())
                .await.unwrap()
                .bytes_stream().map_err(std::io::Error::other);
            let mut reader = tokio_util::io::StreamReader::new(bytes);

            // Append stream to archive
            archive.append(
                format!("{}.mp3", idx), 
                FileDateTime::now(), 
                &mut reader)
            .await.unwrap();     
        }

        archive.finalize().await.unwrap();
    });

    println!("Returning");
    Response::builder()
        .status(StatusCode::OK)
        .header(header::CONTENT_TYPE, "application/zip")
        .body(Body::wrap_stream(ReaderStream::new(r)))
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>> {
    let address = ([127, 0, 0, 1], 8080).into();
    let service =
        make_service_fn(|_| async { Ok::<_, hyper::http::Error>(service_fn(zip_archive)) });
    let server = Server::bind(&address).serve(service);

    println!("Listening on http://{}", address);
    server.await?;

    Ok(())
}

I'm a bit new to Rust, so apologies if there's a super simple mistake that's causing all of this.
I thought at first maybe this was somehow related to the duplex - even though it should be unique per request - so I increased it's size to 16kbs, but it changed nothing and still hangs at 6 streams.
Edit:
After some extra testing, I realized that this is most likely a limit enforced by the browser...?
I've never encountered something like this before, when I try making more than 6 requests on Chromium on Linux, it hangs until another download finishes first. But when I hit the 6th request, if I just make a request on a different browser it works just fine. I can get around ~18 requests at once using this method, but other browsers seem to hang around ~6 requests as well.
Is this something Rust-related, or is it just some limit that I had no idea about?

Looks like the browser: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser

Ah, that's definitely it! I had no idea there was a hard limit on connections per hostname, but it definitely makes sense. Thanks @kmdreko, could you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it? :)
